# How do I remove "None" that appears in the code result?

Tags: python

My code is working, but I want to remove "None" from the output. How can I do it?

```py
def permutation(a,b):
    c = sorted(a)
    d = sorted(b)

    if c == d :
        return print(a," and ", b ," are permutations")
    else:
        count = 0
        for i in c:
            if c in d:
                d.remove(d.index(c))
            else:
                count = count + 1
        return print(a, " and ", b, " are NOT permutations; no. of differences = ", count)

print(permutation([10, 9, 11, 1] , [9,1,11,10] ))
print(permutation([10, 9, 1, 10] , [8,1,11,10]))
```

This is my output:

```
[10, 9, 11, 1]  and  [9, 1, 11, 10]  are permutations
None
[10, 9, 1, 10]  and  [8, 1, 11, 10]  are NOT permutations; no. of differences =  4
None
```

Comment: Your function is returning the return value of `print`, which is None. So your function returns None, and you are printing the return value. Either have your function return a string instead of printing it, or just *call* `permutation(...)` instead of writing `print(permutation(...))`

Comment: Your if statement in the else statement is also incorrect,  you're checking if the `d` list contains the `c` list

Comment: `return print(a," and ", b ," are permutations")` --> `return f'{a} and {b} are permutations'`

Answer (score 1):

Print sends values to the program stdout, it does not attempt to return any value. Any function or method which does not return a value will result in `None` being implicitly returned. This is where the `None` is coming from (you are returning it to `print(permutation(...))`). Try returning a formatted string instead:

```
return f"{a} and {b} are permutations"
...
    return f"{a} and  {b} are NOT permutations; no. of differences = {count}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
def permutation(a,b):
    c = sorted(a)
    d = sorted(b)

    if c == d :
        return (a," and ", b ," are permutations")
    else:
        count = 0
        for i in c:
            if c in d:
                d.remove(d.index(c))
            else:
                count = count + 1
        return (a, " and ", b, " are NOT permutations; no. of differences = ", count)
print(permutation([10, 9, 11, 1] , [9,1,11,10] ))
print(permutation([10, 9, 1, 10] , [8,1,11,10]))
```

in function [return print (something)] is not valid

make like this

```
return print(a," and ", b ," are permutations")
```

```
 ||
 ||
\  /
 \/
```

```
return (a," and ", b ," are permutations")
```